# Global variable in chrome extension's content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to have a global variable inside one **content.js**? Currently, this is my code, but it gives me 'undefined'...

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  // We only accept messages from ourselves
  if (event.source != window)
      return;

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
    url = event.data.text;
    window.username = event.data.subject;
    window.password = event.data.end;
    alert(window.username);
    alert(window.password);
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: url});
  }
}, false);

function get_passwords() { 
    var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(node_list);
    var textboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
        var node = node_list[i];
        console.log(node);
        if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'password') {
            textboxes.push(node);
        }
    } 
    textboxes[0].value = window.password;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your code but I'm thinking maybe the global variables are fine but they are getting their values later than you think. Are you sure that first they got their value , and only later you assign textboxes[0].value = window.password ?

Comment: You code doesn't tell where `get_passwords()` is called. Make sure it happens after the event is triggered. Also, avoid using the variable names `username` and `password`, they have weird behaviors in some browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a chrome extension content script, use this code in

your content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg,sender){

  //msg is the message, sender is where it came from

});
```

and in your background page:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabToSendMessageTo.id, {
     message: {"greeting":"Hello World!"}
});
```

Here's a link to the google documentation for message passing. [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)